# DidSelectRow method is being disabled due to tapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, swift3

Im working on a project in swift 3.0 and I have UIViewController as to fill up few text fields. Thus, I have used a table view as a drop down menu, where once a row is been selected it'll get assigned to a UILabel. In addition I have added a UITapGuestureRecognizer method to make sure the keypad hides once the screen is been tapped. Unfortunately because of this method my didSelectRow is not working,in fact once a row is been tapped the name won't get assigned to the UILable. But when I eliminate the UITapGusture method it works fine. How can I solve this issue and make this work?? The code as bellow.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddRecurringExpensesViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var selectCategoryLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var expenseNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var toTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fromTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var recurringexpenseTypeTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var fromDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var fromDatePickerView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var toDatePickerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var toDatePicker: UIDatePicker!





  var selectCategoryArray = ["Entertainment", "Food", "Membership", "Misc", "Purchase", "Subscription", "Transport", "Utility", "Other"]


 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 self.fromDatePickerView.isHidden = true
 self.toDatePickerView.isHidden = true
 self.recurringexpenseTypeTableView.isHidden = true

 let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddRecurringExpensesViewController.dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

  }
  func dismissKeyboard() {

  view.endEditing(true)
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return selectCategoryArray.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = UITableViewCell ()

  cell.textLabel?.text = selectCategoryArray[indexPath.row]
  return cell
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


  self.selectCategoryLabel.text = selectCategoryArray[indexPath.row]

  print("selected row is \(selectCategoryLabel.text)")


  self.recurringexpenseTypeTableView.isHidden = true
  }
  @IBAction func selectCategoryButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
   self.recurringexpenseTypeTableView.isHidden = false
  }

  @IBAction func fromDateButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

  self.fromDatePickerView.isHidden = false
  }

  @IBAction func fromDateAddedButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
  fromTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from:fromDatePicker.date)
  self.fromDatePickerView.isHidden = true
  }

  @IBAction func toDateButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  self.toDatePickerView.isHidden = false
  }

 @IBAction func toDateAddedButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter ()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
 toTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: toDatePicker.date)
 self.toDatePickerView.isHidden = true
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate on which item?

Comment: It won't allow me to add an answer because it's been marked as duplicate, but an alternative solution could be adding an accessoryView on top of the keypad with a "done" button attached to it. When the "done" button is clicked, it will dismiss the keypad. That should accomplish the same functionality you're looking for. If you use a different type of keyboard you can conform to uitextfielddelegate as well and wire up the "return" button to dismiss the keyboard.